# How to use getActiveElement() inside a shadow root? returns not expected value

Tags: html, webdriver-io

I am having problems getting the html active element inside a shadow root.

The cursor is selecting the input.

```
<part_1>
  #shadow-root
    <input data-field-id="Tp">
</part_1>
```

When I try to do `let active = await browser.getActiveElement()`, instead of returning the input it returns a empty part_1 element. My guess is that it cant return the expected value becaus of the shadow root.
Sorry if my spelling is incorrect, im not a native inglish speaker.